# apple change my JSON format after using URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift3, nsurlsession

I am green to swift 3. In order to transfer data between mysql server and iOS, i try to connect my server and device by `URLSession.Shared.dataTask`.
but the format was changed.

from (the format showed in web)

```
[{"id":"1","names":"abc","pws_1":"password","pws_2":"pw"}]
```

to (the format show in Xcode)

```
Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6200000039e0>( 
{
    names = abc;  
    id = 1;  
    "pws_1" = password; 
    "pws_2" = pw;  
} 
)
)
```

How can I receive data from this "JSONarray"?

P.S.
this is my code:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {

                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                if json != nil{
                    if let Jtwo = json as? [String: Any] {
                        if let names = Jtwo["names"] as? String {
                            print(names)
                        }else{
                            print(Jtwo)
                        }
                    }else{
                        print(json)
                    }
                }else{
                    print("json nil")
                }




                //self.statusL.text = names

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }).resume()
```

Comment: So the question is?

Comment: Nothing has changed, you're just looking at two different things. The first one is a JSON string, the second one is an Optional plist object - this is what you get from NSJSONSerialization without casting the result. Cast this as an array of dictionaries, you'll see. Decoding JSON has been explained so many times here... please do some research. :)

Comment: @Eric Aya: How to cast it?

Comment: @ziplodof.S Show us what you have try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse and access your JSON `Array` like this.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
    if error == nil {
        do {

            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String:Any]]
            if let user = jsonObj.first {
                print(user["names"])
                print(user["id"])
                print(user["pws_1"])
                print(user["pws_2"])
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.label.text = user["names"]
                }

            }
        }
        catch {  
            print(error)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Thx, it's work. but it show up very slow if i label it on the screen.

Comment: You need to update UI on `main` thread check the edited answer.

Comment: @ Nirav D: i would like to UP vote, but i only hv 14 points, i need one more point to hv the privilege.